# Terraform - create azure cost management view using Rest API call via terraform code

Tags: azure, terraform

I want to call Rest API in terraform. Below is the Rest API sample request that needs to be used to create a cost analysis view in Azure. We need to deploy this resource as code using terraform.
In order to create the View/s we can use REST API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/views/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP

we can use this API to Email subscribe by creating scheduled action:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/scheduled-actions/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP

For the second API for scheduled action for email subscription, we should use the payload body  below as example:

```
{
    "kind": "Email",
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "Test ",
        "status": "Enabled",
        "viewId": "/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/{BillingAccountID}/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/views/test",
        "schedule": {
            "frequency": "Weekly",
            "startDate": "2023-01-11T02:30:00.000Z",
            "endDate": "2024-01-10T18:30:00.000Z",
            "daysOfWeek": [
                "Wednesday"
            ]
        },
        "notification": {
            "to": [
                test@microsoft.com
            ],
            "subject": "Test",
            "message": "Test"
        },
        "fileDestination": {
            "fileFormats": [
                "Csv"
            ]
        },
        "scope": "/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/{BillingAccountID}"
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `azapi` provider in terraform to create cost management views and scheduled actions refer to these documentations [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.costmanagement/2019-11-01/views?pivots=deployment-language-terraform#reportconfigdefinition-2)[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.costmanagement/scheduledactions?pivots=deployment-language-terraform) which has the complete schema which parameters that need to be passed.

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MSFT- Used the terraform code block but getting the "Error: `resource_id` and `type` are not matched"

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment .***

Tried with the properties mentioned in your json

Code:

main.tf:

```
   resource "azapi_resource" "symbolicname" {
      name      = "kavyaexample"
      parent_id = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.id
      type      = "Microsoft.CostManagement/views@2019-11-01"
      // location = "eastus"
      body = jsonencode({
        properties = {
          displayName = "myfilefmt"
          fileDestination = {
            fileFormats = "Csv"
          }
          notification = {
            language       = "en"
            message        = "this is test notif"
            regionalFormat = "string"
            subject        = "Test"
            to = [
              "xx@xxx.com"
            ]
          }
          notificationEmail = "string"
          schedule = {
            dayOfMonth = 19
            daysOfWeek = [
              "Thursday"
            ]
            endDate   = "2024-01-10T18:30:00.000Z"
            frequency = "weekly"
            //hourOfDay = int
            startDate = "2023-01-19T11:30:00.000Z"
            weeksOfMonth = [
              "string"
            ]
          }
          "scope" : "/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/xxxxx"
          "status" = "Enabled"
          "viewId" : "/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/xxxxe/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/views/test",
        }
        kind = "Email"
      })
    }
```

[image]

Here install AzApi VSCode Extension to use the AzApi provider

[Microsoft.CostManagement/views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.costmanagement/2019-11-01/views?pivots=deployment-language-terraform#viewproperties-2) support following format as the document .

> ```
> resource "azapi_resource" "symbolicname" {
>   type = "Microsoft.CostManagement/views@2019-11-01"
>   name = "string"
>   parent_id = "string"
>   body = jsonencode({
>     properties = {
>       accumulated = "string"
>       chart = "string"
>       displayName = "string"
>       kpis = [
>         {
>           enabled = bool
>           id = "string"
>           type = "string"
>         }
>       ]
>       metric = "string"
>       pivots = [
>         {  
>          …..
>         }
>       ]
>       query = {
>         dataSet = {
>           aggregation = {}
>           configuration = {
>             columns = [
>               "string"
>             ]
>           }
>           filter = {
>             and = [
>               {
>               dimensions = {
>                 name = "string"
>                 operator = "string"
>                 values = [
>                   "string"
>                 ]
>               }
>               or = [
>                 {
>                 tagKey = {
>                   name = "string"
>                   operator = "string"
>                   values = [
>                     "string"
>                   ]
>                 }
>                 tags = {
>                   name = "string"
>                   operator = "string"
>                   values = [
>                     "string"
>                   ]
>                 }
>                 tagValue = {
>                   name = "string"
>                   operator = "string"
>                   values = [
>                     "string"
>                   ]
>                 }
>           }
>           granularity = "string"
>           grouping = [
>             {
>               name = "string"
>               type = "string"
>             }
>           ]
>           sorting = [
>             {
>               direction = "string"
>               name = "string"
>             }
>           ]
>         }
>         timeframe = "string"
>         timePeriod = {
>           from = "string"
>           to = "string"
>         }
>         type = "Usage"
>       }
>       scope = "string"
>     }
>     eTag = "string"
>   })
> }
> ```

It does not support following parameters.

So received the error:

```
Error: the `body` is invalid: 
│ `properties.fileDestination` is not expected here. Do you mean `properties.metric`? 
│ `properties.notification` is not expected here. Do you mean `properties.modifiedOn`?
```

[image]

Microsoft.CostManagement/scheduledActions has these parameters .
azapi resource of  Microsoft.CostManagement/scheduledActionsParentId can be tried giving as parentId in view .

**Reference :** [Microsoft.CostManagement/scheduledActions - Bicep, ARM template & Terraform AzAPI reference | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.costmanagement/scheduledactions?pivots=deployment-language-terraform)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it taking the example of the answer proposed on this topic:
[Adding filter to azurerm_subscription_cost_management_view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77359145/adding-filter-to-azurerm-subscription-cost-management-view)
This is the code:

```
resource "azurerm_subscription_cost_management_view" "example" {
  name            = "TerraformCostView"
  display_name    = "Terraform - Cost View"
  subscription_id = "/subscriptions/${var.subscription_id}"
  chart_type      = "Area"
  accumulated     = true

  report_type = "Usage"
  timeframe   = "MonthToDate"

  dataset {
    granularity = "Monthly"

    aggregation {
      name        = "totalCost"
      column_name = "Cost"
    }

    #grouping {
    #  name  = "department"
    #  type  = "TagKey"
    #}
  }
  
  pivot {
    name = "ServiceName"
    type = "Dimension"
  }

  pivot {
    name = "ResourceType"
    type = "Dimension"
  }

  pivot {
    name = "ResourceGroupName"
    type = "Dimension"
  }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35211169)